# 3-Col using each colour exactly $|V|/3$ times

Tags: complexity-theory, computability, np-complete, np, decision-problem

Is the following problem in P?

Does a graph $G$ have $3$-colouring, where each colour is used exactly $|V|/3$ times?

I believe it is as we are trying to sample three sets (one for each colour) of vertices without replacement, giving a running time of $O(|V|^5)$. The first set is for three colours, the second for two and third for one col.

Comment: It's NP-complete, by reduction from 3-coloring. Add a big enough independent set.

Comment: I'm not sure where you get $|V|^5$ from. There are something like $\binom{n}{n/3}\binom{2n/3}{n/3}/3!\gg n^5$ possible partitions of the vertex set into three equal parts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the problem is still **NP**-complete.  Suppose you want to know if $G$ is 3-colourable (with no limits on how many vertices can be each colour). Just make a new graph $G^+$ by adding $2|V(G)|$ new vertices with no edges between them, so $|V(G^+)|=3|V(G)|$. If $G$ has a 3-colouring then you can get a "balanced" 3-colouring of $G^+$ by setting the colours of the new vertices appropriately; if $G$ has no 3-colouring, then $G^+$ also has no 3-colouring, so it has no balanced 3-colouring, either.